# install fluxus on ubuntu

Tags: package-management

How can I install Fluxus on ubuntu 16.04?

Fluxus is a rapid prototyping, playing and learning environment that extends Racket, a Lisp and Scheme like language. Racket is still peresent. Until about 2011 (??) Fluxus was supported by ubuntu and in the repository - it is not longer there.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [official website](http://www.pawfal.org/fluxus/packages/) says you can install it from a ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fluxus-maintainers/stable
sudo apt-get install fluxus
```

Comment: That is a lie! Package fluxus is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'fluxus' has no installation candidate I tried to compile from source. ERROR: 'racket3m' must be installed!
Even google does not know racket3m!

Comment: It seems this repository is not being maintained properly. on 16.04 I get this error: `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/fluxus-maintainers/stable/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
` after adding it and run `apt update`

Comment: Indeed not a lie; it's not maintained and it is incredibly cumbersome to build. I am currently trying to build it on Ubuntu; if I succeed I will share.